# Click event on an element and all its children: get attributes of closest parent

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've got a tag that fills in "Event Tracking Paramters" by getting them from element's attributes:
[image]

Element that can be clicked look like this:

```
<a class="js_gtm_test"  data-category="Test" data-action="view"></a>
```

You can see `data-category` and `data-action` attributes specified.

It is fired by this trigger:

[image]

It's working fine unless my element has some children.

```
<a class="js_gtm_test"  data-category="Test" data-action="view"><b>TEST</b> the rest of a link</a>
```

It turns out that when I click bolded text with `<b>`, tag is not fired.

I can modify my trigger to extend CSS selectors it matches like this:

```
.js_gtm_test, .js_gtm_test *
```

After such change, I can see in Preview mode that tag is indeed fired, but "Event Tracking Paramters" are not set correctly (which makes sense, as nested elements do not have `data-category` and `data-action` attributes assigned).

So what I accomplish is: create an event that will fire on `.js_gtm_test` and all its children and if user click one of children, it should take attribute values from its parent.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the `<a>` element and also the element inside it.

You can use `Just Link` trigger and only select the `<a>` element you want.

[image]

Comment: Actually, it would be nice if it worked for other elements than links. But thanks, I will fall back to that if I won't find any better solution

Comment: I remembered this trigger can work with other element inside the `<a>`. If not in your end please let us know.